# Error with UIImagePickerController in XCODE 9

Tags: ios, xcode

when I execute mi code it show an error:

errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

This happens when I select a photo from the library or when I cancel from the library, the problem is that the photo appears but it is not assigned to the variable.

My Code:

```
class DetalleShopViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageDetalle: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDetalle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

var shops: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textFieldDetalle.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (sender as AnyObject? !== saveBtn) {return}
    print("VOY A MANDARLA")
    self.save(name: textFieldDetalle.text!, image: imageDetalle.image!)
    print("MANDADA")
}


@IBAction func cancelar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func seleccionImagen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textFieldDetalle.resignFirstResponder()
    let imagePickerCtrl = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerCtrl.delegate = self
    imagePickerCtrl.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerCtrl.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(imagePickerCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imageDetalle.image = selectedImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying to dismiss self (aka current VC) is cancelling the picker actions?

Try doing

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already try that and the error is kept

Comment: when I select a photo from the library or when I cancel from the library, the problem is that the photo appears but it is not assigned to the variable

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                imageDetalle.image = selectedImage
    }
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

declare ur picker controller as a class variable and set its delegate in viewdidload.